# Will Python type checker respect __annotations__ set dynamically?

Tags: python, type-hinting, python-typing

So I'm reading [PEP 563 -- Postponed Evaluation of Annotations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0563/), where it says:

> In Python 3.10, function and variable annotations will no longer be evaluated at definition time. Instead, a string form will be preserved in the respective `__annotations__` dictionary. **Static type checkers will see no difference in behavior**, whereas tools using annotations at runtime will have to perform postponed evaluation.

Which makes me wonder, if type checkers implement what this PEP suggests, does it mean

```
def f(foo: str):
    pass
```

is equivalent to this form?

```
def f(foo):
    pass

f.__annotations__ = {"foo": "str"}
```

I tested the mypy, PyCharm and pytype, neither respect the dynamically added `__annotations__`. So my question is:

**Is my understanding correct that the type checkers will support it eventually, or I misunderstood the PEP?**

Comment: A **static** type checker will not do **dynamic** analysis, you're reading the PEP incorrectly.  the PEP only makes `from __future__ import annotations` finalized

Comment: No, it's equivalent to `def f(foo: 'str'): ...`.

Comment: Evaluating `__annotations__` would mean the type checker would need to *execute* the file, which may obviously have side effects, and would hence be madness for a *static* type checker.

Comment: Mind explain what the PEP means by `will see no difference in behavior`? This is the part that confuses me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PEP 563 is about the *postponed evaluation* of annotations. It is not about *whether* annotations are stored inside the `__annotations__` attribute. Annotations have been and will be stored in `__annotations__`, only the format in which they are stored changes.

The sentence

> *Static type checkers will see no difference in behavior*

actually means the opposite of what you think: Type Checkers *never* have inspected the `__annotations__` attribute, and as a result will not see any difference.

---

Consider the annotated function `f` and `f.__annotations__` as such:

```
def f(foo: str): ...

print(f.__annotations__)
```

In Python 3.9 or earlier, this prints:

```
{'foo': <class 'str'>}
```

Using `from __future__ import annotations` to enable PEP 563, this prints:

```
{'foo': 'str'}
```

In other words, the type of the `__annotations__` value has changed, but the annotation itself shows no difference. Since type checkers inspect the actual annotation, not the `__annotations__` attribute, they "will see no difference in behaviour" either.

Answer (score 1):

You can store annotations as strings, or put another way, you can annotate with strings:

```
def f(foo: 'bar') -> 'baz':
    ...
```

This is useful/necessary when you'd get unresolvable circular references otherwise:

```
class Foo:
    def bar() -> Foo:  # doesn't resolve, Foo not defined yet
        ...

    def baz() -> 'Foo':  # "workaround"
        ...
```

`from __future__ import annotations` enables this transparently, i.e. even when writing `-> Foo`, it's evaluated as `-> 'Foo'`. This behaviour will become the default in 3.10.

Type checkers won't see any difference because they must already work with this behaviour.

Type checkers won't evaluate `__annotations__` dynamically because that would mean they'd need to actually *execute* the code, which would obviously have side effects, and would hence be madness for a *static* type checker to do.